# Can't complete install CiviCRM in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, installation

Trying to complete Step 4 "Run the Installer" where I go to the index.php page.
Here is my page, I get no install screen -- LINK REMOVED --

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't post a link to an install screen directly. Please edit your post to remove the link.

Secondly, I saw the install page just fine. It has fields for your civicrm and drupal database settings. Do you mean that filling out this information and then clicking "install civicrm" took you to a blank screen?

If you can't see the screen with the fields that need to be filled in I would recommend clearing your browser's cache.

John

Comment: Neat - glad it's working. If you'd tick this as an answer then that helps our points system :)

Comment: Just so that you are aware, although the question has been edited it is still possible to see the link to your site in the edit history.  If you are concerned about this you may want to delete this question.